# receiving "None" as result from solve method in cvxpy

Tags: python, finance, cvxpy, convex-optimization

I am trying to optimize a problem using the cvxpy package but am not getting any return values and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I am running the following code:

```
weights = cp.Variable(6)
risk = cp.quad_form(weights,cov)

allocation_objective = cp.Minimize(risk)

allocation_constraints = [
    cp.sum(weights) == 1,
    (e_r.T @ weights)[0] == 0.3
]

weight_bounds = (0,1)
allocation_constraints.extend(
    [
        weights >= weight_bounds[0],
        weights <= min(weight_bounds[1], 1)
    ]
)

problem = cp.Problem(
    objective=allocation_objective, 
    constraints=allocation_constraints
)
problem.solve()
```

Where cov refers to a 6x6 covariance matrix of asset returns. When this code is run the weights.value is equal to None and the problem.solve() line returns "inf".

I was wondering if anyone could see where this problem has gone wrong and why I am getting my weights.value returning None.

EDIT: Added error trace:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-638c59b13788> in <module>
      3 print(mean_returns)
      4 print(6)
----> 5 mvo.plot_efficient_frontier(covariance=cov, expected_asset_returns=mean_returns, num_assets=6)

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mlfinlab/portfolio_optimization/mean_variance.py in plot_efficient_frontier(self, covariance, expected_asset_returns, num_assets, min_return, max_return, risk_free_rate)
    321                                                    expected_returns=expected_returns,
    322                                                    target_return=portfolio_return,
--> 323                                                    num_assets=num_assets)
    324             volatilities.append(risk)
    325             returns.append(portfolio_return)

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mlfinlab/portfolio_optimization/mean_variance.py in _min_volatility_for_target_return(self, covariance, expected_returns, target_return, num_assets)
    291         problem.solve()
    292         if weights.value is None:
--> 293             raise ValueError('No optimal set of weights found.')
    294         return weights.value, risk.value ** 0.5, target_return
    295 

ValueError: No optimal set of weights found.
```

Comment: I don't think you entered all the required code here or your existing code is incomplete in some fashion.

Comment: @lostin I didn't enter my code where I was creating my covariance matrix, or are you referring to something else missing?

Comment: You should have shown the full error-trace. Guessing, that your solver says it's unbounded, you probably want to constrain your weights to be non-negative. Imagine what happens when the solver is allowed to use `w_i = -10^80` and `w_j = +10^60` `...` while still summing up to 1.

Comment: @sascha Yes sorry I just added the full error-trace now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I am adding it as an answer.

Try using:

```
    problem.solve(solver=SCS)
```